# vb.net: Timeout expired. The timeout period elaspsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm having an error "Timeout expired" whenever I try to generate my reports on my system. It says "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." What could be causing this problem? and whats the possible solution?

I have this 4 tables and each table have 16,000 records below.
I'm guessing that the cause of this error is that the 4 table have too much records.
Heres my query:

```
  SELECT * FROM(SELECT A.ItemNo, A.EquipmentID, A.AssetAccountCode, A.Descrip,  
 B.Condition, B.[Year], C.Brand, c.Model, c.TechnicalSpecs,d.  
[Type],d.Criticallity,d.[Status],(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),d.YearInstalled,127)) as   
Yearinstalled FROM  tbl_Masterlist A JOIN  tbl_Condition B ON A.EquipmentID =  
 B.EquipmentID JOIN  tbl_TechnicalSpecification C ON b.EquipmentID =   
c.EquipmentID JOIN tbl_Status D On c.EquipmentID=d.EquipmentID) src PIVOT  
 (MAX(CONDITION) FOR YEAR IN ([2014], [2015], [2016])) piv
```

Heres  my code on retrieving the result:

```
>  Public Sub Read()
>         Try
>             DS = New DataSet
>             DA = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, db)
>             DA.Fill(DS, 0)
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
>         End Try
>     End Sub



>    Private Sub filldgv()
>         SQLModCons.sql = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT A.ItemNo, A.EquipmentID, A.AssetAccountCode, A.Descrip, B.Condition, B.[Year],
> C.Brand, c.Model,
> c.TechnicalSpecs,d.[Type],d.Criticallity,d.[Status],(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),d.YearInstalled,127))
> as Yearinstalled FROM  tbl_Masterlist A JOIN  tbl_Condition B ON
> A.EquipmentID = B.EquipmentID JOIN  tbl_TechnicalSpecification C ON
> b.EquipmentID = c.EquipmentID JOIN tbl_Status D On
> c.EquipmentID=d.EquipmentID) src PIVOT (MAX(CONDITION) FOR YEAR IN (["
> & year1 & "], [" & year2 & "], [" & year3 & "])) piv "
>         SQLModCons.Read()
>         If Not SQLModCons.DS.Tables.Count = 0 Then
>             dgvReports.DataSource = SQLModCons.DS.Tables(0)
>             Dim rowc As Integer = dgvReports.RowCount.ToString
>             lblCount.Text = rowc
>         End If
>     End Sub



> Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
> System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
>         year1 = cbyear1.Text
>         year2 = cbyear2.Text
>         year3 = cbyear3.Text
>         filldgv()
>     End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried running that query directly to the database? Does it have a large amount of data? If yes, can you show that code on how are you retrieving/calling this query?

Comment: Yes I've tried running it on Management studio and it also takes a lot of time. I'm currently still waiting now, I'ts been 18 minutes.

Comment: Can you show us your code on retrieving the results?

Comment: Public Sub Read()
        Try
            DS = New DataSet
            DA = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, db)
            DA.Fill(DS, 0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try

    End Sub


Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        year1 = cbyear1.Text
        year2 = cbyear2.Text
        year3 = cbyear3.Text
        filldgv()
    End Sub

Comment: Since it's a large result set Try setting the timeout in .NET.

Comment: I think the timeout has something to do with the record, because some of their IDs(EquipmentID) are blank.

Comment: I don't think so. The timeout is occurring because of the large amount of time that the query takes when executing. Because of this, .NET thinks that the database is not responding anymore (as it says in the error _"...operation or the server is not responding..."_.